# Grease Pencil textured strokes transparency issue with other layers

Tags: grease-pencil

I used different grease pencil objects for different elements of my animation (to move/scale them independently) but there's some kind of transparency issue on the strokes. I'd like to have a smooth blending.

However, textured strokes blend nicely when they're on the same GP object.

Is it normal ? If so, is there some workaround ?

Or maybe some rendering issue ?

I searched for individual layers move/scale options, but couldn't find any. I guess there's no such thing.

[image: stroke transparency issue]

I'm using Blender 2.82 (same issue on 2.80) and macOS 10.13.6 (17G8030)

Blend file link : https://gofile.io/?c=3jIdCi

Screen capture of the behaviour : https://gyazo.com/7c6f3de424572ec6bab5fc5436e73339

Comment: Edit : I played a bit with Y positions and now the girl strokes are blending nicely. At some point the house did the same on some frames but it got this blending problem again, really weird.

Comment: So with some help I understood it was mainly a z-fighting issue. Kinda solved. The problem still happens when a grease pencil layer is in front of a background image but I can deal with that.